# Pulling a branch from origin merged it into my local branch and I need to revert that

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I was working on a local branch and I needed to pull down one of the branches from origin so I issued the following command:

git pull origin design

When I did that, that branch ended up being merged into my current local branch which is not what I wanted at all.  So I need to do 2 things:

1. How do I revert this merge back out of my local branch?
2. How do I pull a branch from origin without it doing this merge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To back out a merge commit created by the `pull`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If the merge was a *fast-forward* merge (meaning you hadn't done any work locally), then `git reset --hard` to the sha1 of the last commit you want to keep locally.

To fetch a remote branch without merging:

```
git fetch origin
```

The remote branch will appear as something like `origin/master` (with `git branch -a`).

Comment: It's worth noting that you can customize a `git pull` to be fetch+rebase instead of fetch+merge as well.

Comment: Doesn't `git fetch origin` fetch all the branches of origin? This could potentially be many many branches.

Comment: @Gauthier: Yes, that's correct, but they all appear under the `origin/` namespace.